# Jenkins: Using external scripts vs coding the job in Groovy

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

In a company I'm currently working on, most of our Jenkins jobs are scripted and all they do is call an external script in python or bash, that actually does the heavy work. Something like this:

```
timestamps {
  stage('deploy-site') {
    sh('python deploy-script.py')
  }
}
```

I was wondering if this is actually a good practice and if it would be better to code the job steps using Groovy and the Jenkins API.

Any thoughts? What could be the pros and cons of each approach?

Comment: Stability and security would both certainly increase if you went that route, but there would also be a learning curve and ramp up time for the employees involved.

Comment: To which route are you referring to. Using external scripts for the heavy lifting? or using Groovy and the Jenkins API exclusively?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it depends a lot on what you're using Jenkins for. Jenkins can be used for automating all kinds of things, not just Continuous Integration. I use it for patching servers, applications, and databases, automating Disaster Recovery steps, a full replacement for Cron company-wide, and much more. So in my case there are not a lot of API's within Groovy that handle such things, so my approach is very similar to what you have there. However, I do have a lot of logic built around these processes that is written in Groovy, like knowing where to run things, which server is currently production, which is DR. And I use Groovy functionality for parameters, emailing, moving files etc. And one of the best things is logging. All of my scripts go to STDOUT so that Jenkins captures that and can parse for errors using its log parsing functionality. So even when doing the heavy lifting with shell scripts, Jenkins brings a heck of a lot to enhance that.

Comment: Our use case is very similar to yours, we use Jenkins for a lot of things besides CI, so I guess we're not the only ones doing it this way. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The question is, does someone on the team actually have to run `python deploy-script.py` manually? If yes, then maintaining the `deploy-script.py` is the way to go, since you cannot manually run Jenkins code outside of Jenkins easily.

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully those scripts that are being called are under some sort of version control. If not, having to maintain updates to those scripts if they run on different build nodes could be problematic.

If it's the latter I would put them in a git repo and clone them down for every build, if necessary.

Comment: The scripts are under source control, so, no problem there.

Answer (score 0):

If everyone is a python expert in the team, then why not doing it that way.

I think for putting more logic in jenkins declarative pipeline can help to unifiy the build process across multiple artifacts/teams because it has a certain structure. Also it might help to split between production code and build code.

Answer (score 0):

It's definitely a good practice, especially if the script logic is complex, because it allows you to test the script in isolation, both in a manual and automated fashion.

Besides not having to write complex logic in Groovy, which is not as flexible in my opinion.

Having said that, I agree it also boils down to how much your team is experienced in a given language.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).